# Swift 3: press outside searchBar, search is automatic deleted

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

Configured a searcher in the navigation bar in a UITable. Everything is working fine, accept the fact that when I searched and found the needed cells and I want to click on that cell, the search term is quickly removed from the search bar. The result is that I get back the "old" table. I can not use the search results.

```
Class property: UITableViewController, ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var filteredArray = [Mijnproducten]()
    var shouldShowSearchResults = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


         configureSearchController()

        }

    func configureSearchController() {
        // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        // Place the search bar view to the tableview headerview.
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    }


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        searchWasCancelled = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        shouldShowSearchResults = false
        searchWasCancelled = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        var searchTerm = ""

        if searchWasCancelled {
            searchController.searchBar.text = searchTerm
        }
        else {
            searchTerm = searchController.searchBar.text!
        }
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let text = searchController.searchBar.text
        searchController.searchBar.text = text
        if !shouldShowSearchResults {
            shouldShowSearchResults = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchtext = searchController.searchBar.text
        print(searchtext)

        filteredArray = mijnproducten01.filter{ product in
            return product.productname.lowercased().contains((searchtext?.lowercased())!)
        }
        print(filteredArray)

        if searchtext?.isEmpty == false
        { shouldShowSearchResults = true }
        else
        { shouldShowSearchResults = false }

        // Reload the tableview.
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
      let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! RowTableViewCell
      let RowName = currentCell.ProductLine!.text
      let temp = currentCell.UUID!.text
        print("jaaaa", temp)
      TAGID = Int(temp!)!


        if RowName == "History"
        {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: true)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PropertyToHistory", sender: self)
        }
        else if RowName == "Description"
        {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: true)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PropertyToDescription", sender: self)
        }
        else if RowName == "Transfer"
        {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: true)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PropertyToTransfer", sender: self)
        }
     }
```

Comment: What do you wanna do when cell item is clicked ?

Comment: If I click the cell Item and get a expandable of three get rows the rows point to a next Viewcontroller.

Comment: The problem is in the fact, that the search results are removed when I want to press on the results (infact everey where I press).

Comment: could you tell what have you done in your didselect method of your table ?

Comment: Yes, I added the code in the question.

Comment: I only do not think the problem is there, because I can not even click the cell. When I click something the search is erased and then the "normal" Array is loaded. Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to put breakpoints on your `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`,`searchBarCancelButtonClicked`,`searchBarTextDidEndEditing`,`searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and `updateSearchResults`.
When you select the cell and search result disappears then see where the breakpoint stops.

It seems that there could be logic issues with `shouldShowSearchResults` and `searchWasCancelled`.

Because from what you are saying is correct then somehow your `searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` is triggered which cancels the search. Putting up breakpoints and debugger will get you the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly Im not that professional with swift, when I enable breakpoints, I get a couple surprises. At this moment I do not have time to fix those. But I found the problem, dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation on false..... I have no clue what it does and if it is needed....?

Comment: You can set it false or omit it all together since it's optional. Here is more info about it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618660-dimsbackgroundduringpresentation?language=objc
Accept the answer if it helped :)